# Error on plugin settings page: preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated

Tags: php, error-message, craft4

I've installed the latest CraftCMS version via composer.
When I'm visiting the plugins settings page (/web/admin/settings/plugins), I get the following error message:
[preg_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjxJN.png)

```
Application Info
PHP version                 8.2.13
OS version                  Linux 5.15.74-1-pve
Database driver & version   MariaDB 10.6.12
Image driver & version      Imagick 3.7.0 (ImageMagick 6.9.11-60)
Craft edition & version     Craft Solo 4.5.11.1
Yii version                 2.0.48.1
Twig version                v3.4.3
Guzzle version              7.8.0
```

I'm using PHP 8.2, but I see that passing a null parameter to preg_replace() was also deprecated in PHP8.1. PHP8.0 is EOL. So I'm not sure what to do here.

Comment: Your screenshot is showing a completely different error message than the one mentioned in your post?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting the vendor folder and then running `composer install` this should ensure any cruft that didn't make it quite right through an update is replaced.